# Converting Chinese Characters to Latin Characters in R

Tags: r, iconv, non-latin

Is it possible to convert non Latin Characters, specifically Chinese characters, to Latin characters? I have been reading about the iconv function but I have failed to convert. A simple example is if I want to convert this line to a latin character,

```
h <- "性别,出生日期"
```

how would I do it?

Comment: what do you want to be the result of the conversion?

Comment: I want to convert these characters into utf-8 characters or show the character's equivalent in latin characters. Is this possible?

Comment: @m.alcala You could simply attempt to map the two alphabets, as discussed [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/16174952/1655567). I'm not sure how much sense this would make from a linguistic point of view. For a more generic info on Unicode transformations you may want to have a look at the [**`stringi`**](http://www.r-bloggers.com/icu-unicode-text-transforms-in-the-r-package-stringi/) package.

Comment: How would the latin character look like in your example? Do you mean that the characters are escaped as `\uXXXX` sequences? Or do you mean that the chinese characters are translated in some way?

Comment: If possible, I would like to do the latter, to translate the Chinese Characters in some way. Or let them be identified as an English alphabet.